# regex to stop name part of email being all numbers

Tags: javascript, regex

I have the following email regex which I got from stackoverflow:

`/^(([^<>()\[\]\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@(([^<>()\.,;\s@\"]+\.{0,1})+[^<>()\.,;:\s@\"]{2,})$/`

We want to fail all email addresses that are of this form:

`12121976@example.co.uk`.

How could I update the regex to cover this case?

Comment: What do you mean by "of this form"?

Comment: where every character before the @ sign is numeric

Comment: In that case use guest's answer

Answer (score 2):

You can check if the beginning of the string are digit characters followed by `"@"` character

```
// returns `false` if match is found
!/^\d+(?=@)/.test("12121976@example.co.uk") && /* other `RegExp`s */
```